# Is DiscretizeRegion not yet ready ro discretize 3D-solids?

Tags: regions, geometry, computational-geometry, finite-element-method

In the `DiscretizeRegion` documentation:

> The region reg can be anything that is `ConstantRegionQ` and `RegionEmbeddingDimension` less than or equal to 3.

With `DiscretizeRegion` there could be an easy way to check volume calculations.
First, I do it with a test region:

```
reg3D = ImplicitRegion[x - 2 < y < x - 1 && 0 < z < (x + y)/(x - y),
                       {{x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 0}, {z, 0, 3}}];
{RegionEmbeddingDimension @ reg3D, ConstantRegionQ @ reg3D}
{3, True}

{Volume @ reg3D // N, Volume @ DiscretizeRegion[reg3D]}
{0.375, 0.373509}
```

Now my problem region:

```
reg3D = ImplicitRegion[x - 2 < y < x - 1 && 0 < z < Exp[(x + y)/(x - y)],
                       {{x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 0}, {z, 0, 3}}];
{RegionEmbeddingDimension @ reg3D, ConstantRegionQ @ reg3D}
{3, True}

{vol = Volume @ reg3D, vol // N}
{(3 (-1 + E^2))/(4 E), 1.7628}

Volume @ DiscretizeRegion[reg3D];
```

> `DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion[<<2>>]. >>`

Error; yet another method:

```
g = RegionPlot3D[reg3D, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: region]

```
discreteReg = DiscretizeGraphics[g // Normal] // Quiet;
{RegionDimension @ discreteReg, RegionEmbeddingDimension @ discreteReg}
{2, 3}
```

I am now able to obtain the area:

```
Area @ discreteReg
12.5795
```

but not the volume, it fails once again.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
ToElementMesh @ discreteReg
```

> `MeshRegion::dgcell: The cell Polygon[{41,11121,408,403}] is degenerate. >>
>   ToBoundaryMesh::femtemnm: A mesh could not be generated. >>`

I didn't get much further! What can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on a discussion with the developers, the new default `"MarchingCells"` method (in version 10.2 or later) should be able to handle this, but is running into exception handling problems related to the singularity at `x == y`.

This may be improved in a future version, for now some possible workarounds are below. It is not necessary to fill the interior to compute the volume, so for a crude approximation we may use the `"Legacy"` method to get a boundary representation

```
reg0 = ImplicitRegion[x - 2 < y < x - 1 && 0 < z < Exp[(x + y)/(x - y)],
           {{x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 0}, {z, 0, 3}}];

{bmr0 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg0, Method -> "Legacy"], Volume[bmr0]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which is not a great estimate.

This is an improvement, suggested by [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21), which does fill the interior with 300000 or so tetrahedra.

```
em = NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh[reg0, 
        "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", "SamplePoints" -> 35}];
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ em]

(* 1.74563 *)
```

The following avoids the singularity and uses a finer mesh for a better estimate

```
ϵ = $MachineEpsilon/2; 
reg = ImplicitRegion[x - 2 < y < x - 1 && 0 < z < Exp[(x + y)/(x - y)], 
          {{x, ϵ, 2}, {y, -2, ϵ}, {z, 0, 3}}];
{bmr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001], Volume[bmr]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I hope that the "may", in be improved, is just there as a formality... because there are still a lot of exceptions in these regions related additions, and the potential is big. I'm hopping for fast boolean operations between the different types of regions (discretized, implicit, etc) before release 11...

Comment: Given the `"MarchingCells"` method you mention, does [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96134/12) have an easy solution in Mathematica?